# How to make a Curl equivalent call using Python urllib

Tags: python, curl, urllib2, mixpanel

My working cUrl is as follows:

```
curl https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql \
    -u YOUR_API_SECRET: \
    --data-urlencode script@my_query.js
```

Now I am not able to make it work using `urllib2`, I have tried but getting **(401) error**

```
        url = "https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql"
        token = "MY_TOKEN:"

        request = Request(url)
        request.add_header('-u',  token)
        response = urlopen(request)
```

Any help

Comment: If you can, use [`python-requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/) instead.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil can you provide me an example using python-requests module

Comment: I would have, but I don't understand the `--data-urlencode script@my_query.js` part.

Comment: that you can skip @AshishNitinPatil

Answer (score 0):

I think using requests are a good idea.

```
import requests

requests.get('https://mixpanel.com/api/2.0/jql', auth=('YOUR_API_SECRET', ''))
```

Also if you want to use urllib2 
You can encode the value 
`data = urllib.urlencode(script@my_query.js)`